# Update trigger select fields from same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want an update trigger an a specific field. if that field value is changed i want to insert into a different table selecting all values of the row where update was made even though it was just for one field .

example

```
id--------value1--------value2
1-----------abc ----------efg
```

if value1 is updated to hij, i want to select id(1), value1(hij) and  value2(efg) and insert into a different table.

i cannot do inserted.Id or inserted.value2 since both fields are not updated.

NOTE:  please note only 1 field is updated, other field values are the same before and after, in my question i have just used an example, but in real life a record will be inserted and i am expected to insert the same values onto a different table. but upon insert the record wont be approved until later when approved field value is changed thats when i am expected the bring the values from other fields to different table.

Answer (score 1):

In your `UPDATE` trigger, you have access to the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables which contain the old values (before the `UPDATE`) and the new ones after the `UPDATE`.

So you should be able to write something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Updated
ON dbo.YourTableName
FOR UPDATE
AS
   INSERT INTO dbo.ThisOtherTableOfYours(Id, Value1, Value2)
      SELECT
         i.Id, i.Value1, i.Value2
      FROM 
         Inserted i
      INNER JOIN
         Deleted d ON i.Id = d.Id
      WHERE 
         i.Value1 <> d.Value1
```

The `SELECT` basically joins the two pseudo tables with the old and new values, and selects those rows which have a difference in the `Value1` column.

From those columns, the new values after the update are being inserted into your other table. And the `Inserted` table does contain **ALL** columns (with their new values) from your table - not just those that have been actually updated - **ALL** of them!

Comment: thanks, but please note only 1 field is updated, other field values are the same before and after, in my question i have just used an example, but in real life a record will be inserted and i am expected to insert the same values onto a different table. but the upon insert the record wont be approved untill later when approved field value is changed thats when i am expected the bring the values  from other fields to different table.

Comment: @HakanZim: sure - no problem - this trigger will work in this situation! Trust me! This trigger **will** copy **ALL** the values you require to the other table upon an `UPDATE` ....

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple trigger:

```
create or replace trigger NAME on TABLENAME after update as 
   if :new.value1 = 'hij'{
      insert into OTHERTABLE (id, value1, value2) values (:old.id, :old.value1, :old.value2);
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it'll work for (Microsoft) **SQL Server** - there's no `:new` or `:old` in SQL Server ......

Comment: NOTE: please note only 1 field is updated, other field values are the same before and after, in my question i have just used an example, but in real life a record will be inserted and i am expected to insert the same values onto a different table. but the upon insert the record wont be approved until later when approved field value is changed thats when i am expected the bring the values from other fields to different table.

Comment: What you're trying to create is and audit table, that has all the changes made to an specif table. Later, someone with privileges, will allow or deny the changes?